# how to delete a file with colons in its name

Tags: windows-7, linux, file-management

this one is odd:

I have two partitions on my computer, one for linux (ubuntu 12.latest) and one for window 7. I use grub to choose the system to boot. I made a Screenshot in Linux and saved it on the windows partition, which is mounted in linux with nautilus.

the filename is, or was, i cannot tell if it still exists in reality:

`Screenshot from 2012-08-19 11:01:53.png`

and it is (or was) saved in the windows Desktop folder (c:\Users\<name>\Desktop).

The file never worked because windows told me its demaged, but that does not matter just because I want to **delete** it now, but I cannot.

I tried the `dir /X` - trick, but no short name is generated for this file, I tried the `\\?\c:...` - syntax trick, but it tells me:

`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

and I finally tried to delete it within linux, where for the first try the files could not be deleted and didn't exist anymore at the second try.

I tried a `chkdsk` and it told me: `disk is clean`.

BTW.: I saved another file from linux on the desktop, this time with a valid name and it appears in linux, but not in windows.

What is going on here?

Greetings....

**EDIT::**

I tried FAR but:

[image: error deleting file with FAR]

every kind of file action (i.e. renaming, move and so on) leads to an error.

Comment: Is the file visible from linux now or not?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) can delete files, wich can not delete Windows Explorer, cmd.exe or other file managers. But I can't check it with your example - can't create file with such name ;)

Some symbols (':' too) are forbidden for names in NTFS. So, you have a problems.

Thought, if you need to delete invalid file from Windows directly, you may edit HDD partition with some special tools (WinHex for example) - find file name and change ':' to any other symbol ('_').

Another try - in some cases, deleting via short file name may works (if this file has short file name). You may see the short name in the "dir /X" output, or after pressing Ctrl+N in Far Manager.

Comment: how can i find a file in winhex and change the name there? can i also use the hex plugin within notepad++??

Comment: I was doing this trick lpng ago, not sure, how to find a file name... Try to search for a string. And you may use any editor, which can operate with partitions as raw.

Comment: So, Far is not a solution for ":" contained names. Because it operates with file system via OS API.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll have to delete that file the same way it was created: from the Linux system. The problem is that `:` is used to access [Alternate Data Streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469210%28v=prot.10%29.aspx), but the part after the colon is not an alternate stream in this case. I reproduced your scenario and can confirm your observations. The file doesn't have an 8.3 name, and removing it via `\\.\C:\...` does not work. Same goes for trying to remove the containing folder or using Microsoft's [Services for UNIX](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2391). You could try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), but I suspect that won't be much different from SFU.

Bottom line: your best bet is to boot into Linux and delete the file from there.